# What are the four rules, that the 2D subdivision matrix describes?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, meshing

I got the following 2D subdivision mask (which is used to subdivide a given quad-mesh):

$$
M = \frac{1}{8}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1\\
3 & 6 & 3\\
3 & 6 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now I need to know, which *four* rules this matrix describes, to compute one new vertex for each rule. I know, that I need to have a look at the odd/even (row/column) indices in the matrix.

| Row | Column | Rule |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Odd | Odd | $$ M = \frac{1}{8} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & X & 1\\ X & X & X\\ 3 & X & 3\\ X & X & X\\ \end{bmatrix} $$ |
| Odd | Even | $$ M = \frac{1}{8} \begin{bmatrix} X & 2 & X\\ X & X & X\\ X & 6 & X\\ X & X & X\\ \end{bmatrix} $$ |
| Even | Odd | $$ M = \frac{1}{8} \begin{bmatrix} X & X & X\\ 3 & X & 3\\ X & X & X\\ 1 & X & 1\\ \end{bmatrix} $$ |
| Even | Even | $$ M = \frac{1}{8} \begin{bmatrix} X & X & X\\ X & 6 & X\\ X & X & X\\ X & 2 & X\\ \end{bmatrix} $$ |

Can someone help me and explain, what the rules mean? I already encountered a subdivision mask (square matrix) of size 5x5 and where I knew, what the rules mean. For example with

$$
M = \frac{1}{64}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4  & 6  & 4  & 1\\
4 & 16 & 24 & 16 & 4\\
6 & 24 & 36 & 24 & 6\\
4 & 16 & 24 & 16 & 4\\
1 & 4  & 6  & 4  & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the odd/odd index rule defines the calculation of a new position of the given vertices of the mesh. The odd/even rule defines the calculation of new vertices on the horizontal edges between vertices, while the even/odd rule defines the calculation of new vertices on the vertical edges. The even/even rule is then important for placing new vertices in the middle of the quad faces of the mesh.

But with a matrix, which is not squared, I am a bit confused, how to read the rules.

Comment: Where did you get these rules?  It should be explained in your text.  What are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: I tried to concretize the question. Maybe now it is a bit clearer.

Comment: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask.